# How to get Djangos urls.py to look into database and take urls from it? Is that even a good idea?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I have some problems to gasp how to deal with dynamic urls. I want to use the django admin backend to add pages which are saved into a database via an app model.
For example i have a field in the database called page_url generated by my apps models.py. In my Django backend one can choose a unique url name like "home" etc. This field i want to turn into a url. How can I get this done?

Currently i'm trying to use urls.py to do this.

given the following urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$',index),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

How can I bring urls.py to look into my database and iterate over all page_url so that the html request to www.example.com/home/ (example)will proceed? Is it even a good way to get django dealing with urls which are not hard-coded into urls.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you should do the following: define your URL:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$',index),
    )
```

and in the view `index` you can access your url from `request` variable. Then you can read your database and compare url to one in database. Note that there are frameworks which will do that for you like [flatpages.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/)

Comment: and don't forget to escape your database stuff. No need to turn your url into an sql injection vector.

Comment: @freakish thanks for your answer. I know how to query the database from a view. But how can i integrate urls which are written into the database into urls.py? How does django know that there is a new url in the database which he should treat in a certain way...via views etc. I know that there is flatpages...but i want to do it by myself

Comment: @Jurudocs url is stored in `request.path`. When your `index` view is given by `(r'^$', index)` and this url is first on the list, then every url will hit this view (because this regexp matches everything). So in your `index` view you need to read the path and compare it to database. Read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/ for more info.

Comment: @freakish thanks again for your comment. i guess I have to explain it a better way...I know how to handle a matching url pattern with a view. But the whole concept is too static for what i need. I want to take this project more into the direction of an cms. If the admin adds a site and adds a url for this site in the backend. How do i get urls.py know, that there is a new site? (user enters url in backend--> DB saves it--> how to make urls.py know that there is a new url to be handled...i hope now its more clear what i want...

Comment: I don't think it can handle what you're trying to do. I think the suggestion in this answer is to create a "dynamic" urls.py, but because django doesn't have the ability to do this automatically, you simulate it by writing a view which compares the url of the requested page to available urls in the database.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I misunderstood. I don't think there is a way to map database urls into urls.py file. And even if there is I don't see the reason for doing this. Think about this like this: how can you dynamically add Python scripts (views) to your application (adding urls means also adding views)? Actually you can also store Django views in database (raw string which you call by `exec` in python) but this is definitely not a good practice. By the way, Jurudocs - why do you need it in urls.py? Sometimes the normal way *IS* the best way. :)